# Group rows with start- end date by month on PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a database with a tbl_registration with rows that look like

```
ID | start_date_time | end_date_time | ...
1 | 2021-01-01 14:00:15 | 2021-01-01 14:00:15
2 | 2021-02-01 14:00:15 | null
4 | 2021-05-15 14:00:15 | 2024-01-01 14:00:15
5 | 2019--15 14:00:15 | 2024-01-01 14:00:15
```

endDate can be null
It contains 500.000 - 1.000.000 of records

We want to create an overview of year grouped by month that shows the amount of records that are active in that month. So a registration is counted per month if it lies (partially) in that month based on start and end date.

I can do a query per month like this

```
select  count (id)
from tbl_registration
  where
 (r.end_date_time >= to_timestamp('01/01/2021 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  or r.end_date_time is null )
  and r.start_date_time < to_timestamp('01/02/2021 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

But that forces me to repeat this query 12 times.
I don't see a creative way to solve this in one query that would give me as a result 12 rows, one for each month

I've been looking at the generate_series function, but I don't see how I can group on the comparison of those start- and end dates

Answer (score 1):

Postgres supports `generate_series()` . . . so generate the dates you want then then construct the query.  One method is:

```
select gs.mon, x.cnt
from generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-12-01'::date, interval '1 month') gs(mon) left join lateral
     (select  count(*) as cnt
      from tbl_registration
      where r.end_date_time >= gs.mon or r.end_date_time is null) and
            r.start_date_time < gs.mon + interval '1 month'
     )  x
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: I deleted my previous comment, had an error in the date selection.
This give me the functional response, thanks! However it is slower as doing the queries one by one

Comment: @Joris . . . I would be surprised if the performance is much different from 12 queries.  If performance is an issue, ask a new question and give more details about the tables, sizes, and indexes.